# 403 Forbidden when I try to access my website without www

Tags: http-status-code-403

I'm facing a strange problem.

I can access my website with :

- https://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://example.com

But I can't access to it by tipping :

- http://example.com
- example.com

I try to put an `.htaccess` to redirect the non www to the www version but it doesn't work.

```
# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might come from your DNS settings. 
You need to create a record for your domain name without the leading "www.": it should be an A record with the name of “@” that points to your server IP